# Spacing in Table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want the text in the cells vertically centered. I tried the following code but the first row is not vertically centered. How can I fix this problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % linksbündig mit Breitenangabe
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % zentriert mit Breitenangabe
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % rechtsbündig mit Breitenangabe
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{C{1cm}|C{1cm}C{1cm}C{1cm}C{1cm}C{1cm}N}\toprule
 $X,Y$      & $1$          & $2$     & $5$     & $7$     & $8$     & \\[3pt]\midrule
 $1$        & $0,08$       & $0,02$  & $0,04$  & $0,12$  & $0,06$  & \\[3pt]
 $2$        & $0,10$       & $0,05$  & $0,07$  & $0,12$  & $0,04$  & \\[3pt]
 $3$        & $0,03$       & $0,04$  & $0,07$  & $0,10$  & $0,06$  & \\[3pt] 
 \end{tabular}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to the issue but please keep in mind that horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package (such as `\toprule`,...)  are intended to be used without vertical lines. As you can see, there currently is a small gap around the intersection of a vertical and horizontal line.

Comment: Is there a special reason for using a fixed width column type here? Wouldn't a simple `c` type column be sufficient here?

Comment: In fact, all rows are not vertically centered in your table due to the manula spacing `[3pt]` you added below each row. Remove them and the cells will be centered. If you want to increase the row height symmetrically, you could take a look at the `cellspace` package.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are different versions of your table using `siunitx`, `cellspace` and/or `booktabs`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{siunitx} % used in example 1-4
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace} % used in example 3
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt} % spacing can be adapted to your needs
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\cellspacetoplimit}

\usepackage{booktabs} % used in example 4


\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

With siunitx and natural width columns:

\begin{tabular}{c|*{5}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
 \hline
 {X,Y}    & {1}        & {2}   & {5}   & {7}   & {8}    \\
 \hline
 1        & 0,08       & 0,02  & 0,04  & 0,12  & 0,06   \\
 2        & 0,10       & 0,05  & 0,07  & 0,12  & 0,04   \\
 3        & 0,03       & 0,04  & 0,07  & 0,10  & 0,06   \\ 
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

with siunitx and fixed width columns:

{
\sisetup{table-column-width=1cm}
\begin{tabular}{c|*{5}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
 \hline
 {X,Y}    & {1}        & {2}   & {5}   & {7}   & {8}    \\
 \hline
 1        & 0,08       & 0,02  & 0,04  & 0,12  & 0,06   \\
 2        & 0,10       & 0,05  & 0,07  & 0,12  & 0,04   \\
 3        & 0,03       & 0,04  & 0,07  & 0,10  & 0,06   \\ 
\end{tabular}
}

\bigskip
 
with siunitx, natural width columns and additional vertical white space:

\begin{tabular}{0c|*{5}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
 \hline
 {X,Y}    & {1}        & {2}   & {5}   & {7}   & {8}    \\
 \hline
 1        & 0,08       & 0,02  & 0,04  & 0,12  & 0,06   \\
 2        & 0,10       & 0,05  & 0,07  & 0,12  & 0,04   \\
 3        & 0,03       & 0,04  & 0,07  & 0,10  & 0,06   \\ 
\end{tabular}

\bigskip


with siunitx, natural width columns and horizontal lines from booktabs:

\begin{tabular}{c*{5}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
 \toprule
 {X,Y}    & {1}        & {2}   & {5}   & {7}   & {8}    \\
 \midrule
 1        & 0,08       & 0,02  & 0,04  & 0,12  & 0,06   \\
 2        & 0,10       & 0,05  & 0,07  & 0,12  & 0,04   \\
 3        & 0,03       & 0,04  & 0,07  & 0,10  & 0,06   \\
 \bottomrule 
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an `array` if you have only math cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}} % linksbündig mit Breitenangabe
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}} % zentriert mit Breitenangabe
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft}p{#1}} % rechtsbündig mit Breitenangabe
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

{\def\arraystretch{1.5}
$\begin{array}{C{1cm}|C{1cm}C{1cm}C{1cm}C{1cm}C{1cm}}\toprule
X,Y      & 1          & 2     & 5     & 7     & 8      \\\midrule
 1        & 0,08       & 0,02  & 0,04  & 0,12  & 0,06   \\
 2        & 0,10       & 0,05  & 0,07  & 0,12  & 0,04   \\
 3        & 0,03       & 0,04  & 0,07  & 0,10  & 0,06  
\end{array}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]